# Const pointer to pointer to const int casts to const pointer to pointer to int

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, casting, constants

Here's the code:

```
int *const *a = nullptr;
int const *const *b = nullptr;

b = a;
```

Why does this code compile and run without error? Doesn't const pointer mean that we can't change it?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I use C++ language, standard C++-11

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is an error in my thoughts: I thought that `b` was `const` and so couldn't be assigned to.  But `b` is modifiable (though what it points to is `const`), so it's possible to assign to `b`.

In other words, `int const *const *b` isn't a `const` pointer but is actualy a pointer to `const` pointer, so it can be changed.

Comment: @TobySpeight How is this not an answer?  The OP did not understand what was going on (in that it seemed to violate const correctness).  This answers the problem (there is no const correctness violation).

Comment: @Yakk I should have read the answer more carefully.  You're right.  I thought the confusion was about the type compatibility; it didn't occur to me that the confusion was with `int *const *const`.  I've withdrawn my criticism.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a pointer to a const-pointer to const int.  It is permissible to assign it to point to a const-pointer to (writable) int because if you were to dereference `*b`, then you would be able to read through it.

On the other hand `a=b` would fail to compile, because that would make a pointer to (writable) int point to const int, and thus be able to write to something you shouldn't.  The type system prevents this.

It gets more interesting when you consider also:

```
int const **c;
int **d;
```

**Exercise:** What assignments are permissible between a, b, c & d?  Why?

Comment: `a = a` — is **ok**, assign pointer to another pointer, both pointing to the same type.
`a = b` — _fail_ (you've explained it)
`a = c` — _fail_. We've also creating a pointer to writable int point to const int.
`a = d`; — seems **ok**. We assign it to point everything after last pointer to `int *` which seems right.

`b = a` — **ok** (you've described it)
`b = b` — **ok**. Pointer of one type to pointer of same type.
`b = c` — **ok**. Pointer of one const type to another pointer of writeable type. We still can read.
`b = d` — **ok**. Same as one above.

Continue in another comment.

Comment: `c = a` — _fail_. We assign `c` to point to a pointer to int, so we can change const. Bad.
`c = b` — _fail_. We assign 'c' to point to non-const pointer, which can be changed (? not sure of this one).
`c = c` — **ok**. Pointer of one type to pointer of same type.
`c = d` — _fail_ (?). Absolutely not sure of this. Does it have something to do with changing `int const` via `d`?

`d = a` — _fail_. We can change pointer, which is pointed and const.
`d = b` — _fail_. Same as example above.
`d = c` — _fail_ (?). Also a problem with understanding, same as `c = d`. No idea.
`d = d` — **ok**. Obvious,

Comment: It's actually extremely easy to mess this things up, I've got many problems trying to understand pointers and don't see any unique rules which can help to sort everything out :(